# Solid View better recognizable?

Tags: materials, objects, 3d-view, camera

is there a way to change the Material for the Solid View? 
Like in 3ds Max you can change to Clay Mode for Example.
I wouldn't mind with a normal grey object but somehow in Blender the Objects have such a weird lighting that its difficult to recognize edges in my objects.

I'm not talking about wireframe mode. I dont want to see every edge n my object. But when for example i extrude minimally into the surface then its hard to see without turning the camera until you have an angle on it that lights it with good difference.

Hope you can understand what I mean.

Thanks

Comment: Did you already tried Matcaps&Ambient acclusion for the viewport? What are the features that you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in solid view in viewport, open up the right toolbox by pressing N. Down there, under shading, activate Matcap and Ambient Occlusion. This improves the view remarkably. If there is another way to improve the viewport, especially with large grayscale models, I'd like to hear.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. That improves the view enough for me. :)

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, please accept my answer as the correct one, since this site is based on reputation.   :)

Answer (score 0):

For Blender 2.8 and later, on top-right corner you will find a drop-down menu. In there you will find the **Viewport Shading** options.

Select MatCap, activate Shadow, Cavity, Color etc to your liking. Selecting "*Single*" in "*Color*" option will let you pick color of the objects in viewport.

[image]